# Reading different types of data from a file without arrays

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that states the following: The state weather service gathers precipitation information from 78 high-elevation locations across the state. The file monthlyPrecipitation.txt has the monthly precipitation amounts for all 78 of those weather stations. Write a program that reads the data in the monthlyPrecipitation.txt file and creates a report that looks like:

Annual Precipitation Report

```
Weather Station       Elevation  Precipitation
AGUA CANYON            8900        26.1
BEAVER DAMS            8000        28.1
BEAVER DIVIDE          8280        30.5
```

is there any way that I can read a file by separate type of data and then write it to another file without using arrays?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way that I can read a file by separate type of data and then write it to another file without using arrays?

Sure, you can just input a set of data, and output that set of data to the target file immediately without using an array.